# Sending event when AngularJS finished loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Wondered what's the best way to detect the finish of page loading/bootstrapping, when all directives done compiling/linking.

Any event already there? Should I overload the bootstrap function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Angular hasn't provided a way to signal when a page finished loading, maybe because **"finished" depends on your application**. For example, if you have hierarchical tree of partials, one loading the others. "Finish" would mean that all of them have been loaded. Any framework would have a hard time analyzing your code and understanding that everything is done, or still waited upon. For that, you would have to provide application-specific logic to check and determine that.

Answer (score 207):

Just a hunch: why not look at how the ngCloak directive does it? Clearly the ngCloak directive manages to show content after things have loaded. I bet looking at ngCloak will lead to the exact answer...

**EDIT 1 hour later:**
Ok, well, I looked at [ngCloak](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngCloak.js) and it's really short. What this obviously implies is that the compile function won't get executed until {{template}} expressions have been evaluated (i.e. the template it loaded), thus the nice functionality of the ngCloak directive.

My educated guess would be to just make a directive with the same simplicity of ngCloak, then in your compile function do whatever you want to do. :) Place the directive on the root element of your app. You can call the directive something like myOnload and use it as an attribute my-onload. The compile function will execute once the template has been compiled (expressions evaluated and sub-templates loaded).

**EDIT, 23 hours later:**
Ok, so I did some research, and I also [asked my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719622/why-does-the-link-function-of-my-directive-never-get-called). The question I asked was indirectly related to this question, but it coincidentally lead me to the answer that solves this question.

The answer is that you can create a simple directive and put your code in the directive's link function, which (for most use cases, explained below) will run when your element is ready/loaded. Based on [Josh's description of the order in which compile and link functions are executed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/bBgJ6Tb-mHo/PDSU76pNPtAJ),

> if you have this markup:
>
> ```
> <div directive1>
>   <div directive2>
>     <!-- ... -->
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Then AngularJS will create the directives by running directive
>   functions in a certain order:
>
> ```
> directive1: compile
>   directive2: compile
> directive1: controller
> directive1: pre-link
>   directive2: controller
>   directive2: pre-link
>   directive2: post-link
> directive1: post-link
> ```
>
> By default a straight "link" function is a post-link, so your outer
>   directive1's link function will not run until after the inner
>   directive2's link function has ran. That's why we say that it's only
>   safe to do DOM manipulation in the post-link. So toward the original
>   question, there should be no issue accessing the child directive's
>   inner html from the outer directive's link function, though
>   dynamically inserted contents must be compiled, as said above.

From this we can conclude that we can simply make a directive to execute our code when everything is ready/compiled/linked/loaded:

```
    app.directive('ngElementReady', [function() {
        return {
            priority: -1000, // a low number so this directive loads after all other directives have loaded. 
            restrict: "A", // attribute only
            link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
                console.log(" -- Element ready!");
                // do what you want here.
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Now what you can do is put the ngElementReady directive onto the root element of the app, and the `console.log` will fire when it's loaded:

```
<body data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-element-ready="">
   ...
   ...
</body>
```

It's that simple! Just make a simple directive and use it. ;)

You can further customize it so it can execute an expression (i.e. a function) by adding `$scope.$eval($attributes.ngElementReady);` to it:

```
    app.directive('ngElementReady', [function() {
        return {
            priority: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, // execute last, after all other directives if any.
            restrict: "A",
            link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
                $scope.$eval($attributes.ngElementReady); // execute the expression in the attribute.
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Then you can use it on any element:

```
<body data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="BodyCtrl" data-ng-element-ready="bodyIsReady()">
    ...
    <div data-ng-element-ready="divIsReady()">...<div>
</body>
```

Just make sure you have your functions (e.g. bodyIsReady and divIsReady) defined in the scope (in the controller) that your element lives under.

Caveats: I said this will work for *most* cases. Be careful when using certain directives like ngRepeat and ngIf. They create their own scope, and your directive may not fire. For example if you put our new ngElementReady directive on an element that also has ngIf, and the condition of the ngIf evaluates to false, then our ngElementReady directive won't get loaded. Or, for example, if you put our new ngElementReady directive on an element that also has a ngInclude directive, our directive won't be loaded if the template for the ngInclude does not exist. You can get around some of these problems by making sure you nest the directives instead of putting them all on the same element. For example, by doing this:

```
<div data-ng-element-ready="divIsReady()">
    <div data-ng-include="non-existent-template.html"></div>
<div>
```

instead of this:

```
<div data-ng-element-ready="divIsReady()" data-ng-include="non-existent-template.html"></div>
```

The ngElementReady directive will be compiled in the latter example, but it's link function will not be executed. Note: directives are always compiled, but their link functions are not always executed depending on certain scenarios like the above.

**EDIT, a few minutes later:**

Oh, and to fully answer the question, you can now `$emit` or `$broadcast` your event from the expression or function that is executed in the `ng-element-ready` attribute. :) E.g.:

```
<div data-ng-element-ready="$emit('someEvent')">
    ...
<div>
```

**EDIT, even more few minutes later:**

@satchmorun's answer works too, but only for the initial load. Here's a [very useful SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation) that describes the order things are executed including link functions, `app.run`, and others. So, depending on your use case, `app.run` might be good, but not for specific elements, in which case link functions are better.

**EDIT, five months later, Oct 17 at 8:11 PST:**

This doesn't work with partials that are loaded asynchronously. You'll need to add bookkeeping into your partials (e.g. one way is to make each partial keep track of when its content is done loading then emit an event so the parent scope can count how many partials have loaded and finally do what it needs to do after all partials are loaded).

**EDIT, Oct 23 at 10:52pm PST:**

I made a simple directive for firing some code when an image is loaded:

```
/*
 * This img directive makes it so that if you put a loaded="" attribute on any
 * img element in your app, the expression of that attribute will be evaluated
 * after the images has finished loading. Use this to, for example, remove
 * loading animations after images have finished loading.
 */
  app.directive('img', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
        $element.bind('load', function() {
          if ($attributes.loaded) {
            $scope.$eval($attributes.loaded);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

**EDIT, Oct 24 at 12:48am PST:**

I improved my original `ngElementReady` directive and renamed it to `whenReady`.

```
/*
 * The whenReady directive allows you to execute the content of a when-ready
 * attribute after the element is ready (i.e. done loading all sub directives and DOM
 * content except for things that load asynchronously like partials and images).
 *
 * Execute multiple expressions by delimiting them with a semi-colon. If there
 * is more than one expression, and the last expression evaluates to true, then
 * all expressions prior will be evaluated after all text nodes in the element
 * have been interpolated (i.e. {{placeholders}} replaced with actual values). 
 *
 * Caveats: if other directives exists on the same element as this directive
 * and destroy the element thus preventing other directives from loading, using
 * this directive won't work. The optimal way to use this is to put this
 * directive on an outer element.
 */
app.directive('whenReady', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, // execute last, after all other directives if any.
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
      var expressions = $attributes.whenReady.split(';');
      var waitForInterpolation = false;

      function evalExpressions(expressions) {
        expressions.forEach(function(expression) {
          $scope.$eval(expression);
        });
      }

      if ($attributes.whenReady.trim().length == 0) { return; }

      if (expressions.length > 1) {
        if ($scope.$eval(expressions.pop())) {
          waitForInterpolation = true;
        }
      }

      if (waitForInterpolation) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function checkIfInterpolated() {
          if ($element.text().indexOf($interpolate.startSymbol()) >= 0) { // if the text still has {{placeholders}}
            requestAnimationFrame(checkIfInterpolated);
          }
          else {
            evalExpressions(expressions);
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        evalExpressions(expressions);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

For example, use it like this to fire `someFunction` when an element is loaded and `{{placeholders}}` not yet replaced:

```
<div when-ready="someFunction()">
  <span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.property}}</span>
</div>
```

`someFunction` will be called before all the `item.property` placeholders are replaced.

Evaluate as many expressions as you want, and make the last expression `true` to wait for `{{placeholders}}` to be evaluated like this:

```
<div when-ready="someFunction(); anotherFunction(); true">
  <span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.property}}</span>
</div>
```

`someFunction` and `anotherFunction` will be fired after `{{placeholders}}` have been replaced.

This only works the first time an element is loaded, not on future changes. It may not work as desired if a `$digest` keeps happening after placeholders have initially been replaced (a $digest can happen up to 10 times until data stops changing). It'll be suitable for a vast majority of use cases.

***EDIT, Oct 31 at 7:26pm PST:***

Alright, this is probably my last and final update. This will probably work for 99.999 of the use cases out there:

```
/*
 * The whenReady directive allows you to execute the content of a when-ready
 * attribute after the element is ready (i.e. when it's done loading all sub directives and DOM
 * content). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968690/sending-event-when-angular-js-finished-loading
 *
 * Execute multiple expressions in the when-ready attribute by delimiting them
 * with a semi-colon. when-ready="doThis(); doThat()"
 *
 * Optional: If the value of a wait-for-interpolation attribute on the
 * element evaluates to true, then the expressions in when-ready will be
 * evaluated after all text nodes in the element have been interpolated (i.e.
 * {{placeholders}} have been replaced with actual values).
 *
 * Optional: Use a ready-check attribute to write an expression that
 * specifies what condition is true at any given moment in time when the
 * element is ready. The expression will be evaluated repeatedly until the
 * condition is finally true. The expression is executed with
 * requestAnimationFrame so that it fires at a moment when it is least likely
 * to block rendering of the page.
 *
 * If wait-for-interpolation and ready-check are both supplied, then the
 * when-ready expressions will fire after interpolation is done *and* after
 * the ready-check condition evaluates to true.
 *
 * Caveats: if other directives exists on the same element as this directive
 * and destroy the element thus preventing other directives from loading, using
 * this directive won't work. The optimal way to use this is to put this
 * directive on an outer element.
 */
app.directive('whenReady', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, // execute last, after all other directives if any.
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
      var expressions = $attributes.whenReady.split(';');
      var waitForInterpolation = false;
      var hasReadyCheckExpression = false;

      function evalExpressions(expressions) {
        expressions.forEach(function(expression) {
          $scope.$eval(expression);
        });
      }

      if ($attributes.whenReady.trim().length === 0) { return; }

    if ($attributes.waitForInterpolation && $scope.$eval($attributes.waitForInterpolation)) {
        waitForInterpolation = true;
    }

      if ($attributes.readyCheck) {
        hasReadyCheckExpression = true;
      }

      if (waitForInterpolation || hasReadyCheckExpression) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function checkIfReady() {
          var isInterpolated = false;
          var isReadyCheckTrue = false;

          if (waitForInterpolation && $element.text().indexOf($interpolate.startSymbol()) >= 0) { // if the text still has {{placeholders}}
            isInterpolated = false;
          }
          else {
            isInterpolated = true;
          }

          if (hasReadyCheckExpression && !$scope.$eval($attributes.readyCheck)) { // if the ready check expression returns false
            isReadyCheckTrue = false;
          }
          else {
            isReadyCheckTrue = true;
          }

          if (isInterpolated && isReadyCheckTrue) { evalExpressions(expressions); }
          else { requestAnimationFrame(checkIfReady); }

        });
      }
      else {
        evalExpressions(expressions);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Use it like this

```
<div when-ready="isReady()" ready-check="checkIfReady()" wait-for-interpolation="true">
   isReady will fire when this {{placeholder}} has been evaluated
   and when checkIfReady finally returns true. checkIfReady might
   contain code like `$('.some-element').length`.
</div>
```

Of course, it can probably be optimized, but I'll just leave it at that. [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) is nice.

Comment: Really annoying with all those "data-" prefixes. I am glad I do not use them myself.

Comment: @stolsvik heh, yeah, in the most modern browsers they are not needed.

Comment: Deserves up vote for amount of time and effort put into this answer. Nice work!

Comment: @trusktr they are not needed in any browsers. It's a matter of forwar compability rather then backwards. I.e to ensure that in furure no attribute ng-*** after becoming HTML standart will not break your Angular app.
Generally, those who don't use data- just assume that ng-*** will never be introduced into HTML as native attribute.

Comment: Nice answer, but please consider removing all the "Edit" lines and restructuring your answer a bit. The edit history is available via the "edited ..." link at the bottom of your answer, and it distracts while reading.

Comment: I suggest you re-structure the answer as @Stijn said + adding the source code to github to be reusable in the future

Comment: The source code would be really helpfull. And if you can make it public on npm, that'd be PERFECT. Really nice answer, really nicely explained, +1 for the ammount of effort put into this.

Comment: Why use requestAnimationFrame and not simply $timeout? requestAnimationFrame seems specifically meant for animations.

Comment: You really deserve an vote for your patience to explain this in detail.

Comment: @mcv Honestly, I'm not sure rAF is any better than setTimeout or setInterval other than the fact that the timing is more consistent. This can probably use $timeout as well.

Answer (score 38):

In the [docs for `angular.Module`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module), there's an entry describing the `run` function:

> Use this method to register work which should be performed when the injector is done loading all modules.

So if you have some module that is your app:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [/* module dependencies */]);
```

You can run stuff after the modules have loaded with:

```
app.run(function() {
  // Do post-load initialization stuff here
});
```

#### EDIT: Manual Initialization to the rescue

So it's been pointed out that the `run` doesn't get called when the DOM is ready and linked up. It gets called when the `$injector` for the module referenced by `ng-app` has loaded all its dependencies, which is separate from the DOM compilation step.

I took another look at [manual initialization](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), and it seems that this should do the trick.

[I've made a fiddle to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/FZcZ4/1/).

The HTML is simple:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <test-directive>This is a test</test-directive>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the lack of an `ng-app`. And I have a directive that will do some DOM manipulation, so we can make sure of the order and timing of things.

As usual, a module is created:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

And here's the directive:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="test-directive"><h1><div ng-transclude></div></h1></div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        compile: function() {
            console.log("Compiling test-directive");
            return {
                pre: function() { console.log("Prelink"); },
                post: function() { console.log("Postlink"); }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

We're going to replace the `test-directive` tag with a `div` of class `test-directive`, and wrap its contents in an `h1`.

I've added a compile function that returns both pre and post link functions so we can see when these things run.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
// The bootstrapping process

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// Check that our directive hasn't been compiled

function howmany(classname) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(classname).length;
}
```

Before we've done anything, there should be no elements with a class of `test-directive` in the DOM, and after we're done there should be 1.

```
console.log('before (should be 0):', howmany('test-directive'));

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    // Bootstrap the body, which loades the specified modules
    // and compiled the DOM.
    angular.bootstrap(body, ['app']);

    // Our app is loaded and the DOM is compiled
    console.log('after (should be 1):', howmany('test-directive'));
});
```

It's pretty straightforward. When the document is ready, call `angular.bootstrap` with the root element of your app and an array of module names.

In fact, [if you attach a `run` function to the `app` module](http://jsfiddle.net/FZcZ4/2/), you'll see it gets run before any of the compiling takes place.

If you run the fiddle and watch the console, you'll see the following:

```
before (should be 0): 0 
Compiling test-directive 
Prelink
Postlink
after (should be 1): 1 <--- success!
```

Comment: thanks @satchmorun! but run() executes before the end of the linking part - just verified it with some console.logs.

Comment: was curious myself... I have a directive that fires to implement some jQuery DOM plugins, `run` fires before the directive and when run fires, html is not all there

Comment: @charlietfl - I dug a little bit into manual bootstrapping, and it's actually a pretty easy way to get what the question is looking for. I've adding a pretty lengthy edit to my original answer.

Comment: i found that using `$timeout( initMyPlugins,0)` works within my directive, all the html I need is there

Comment: @satchmorun, see this follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989161/angular-js-evalasync-not-called

Comment: It doesn't work very well if you're using `templateUrl`

Comment: does this require removing ng-app from the markup altogether?

Answer (score 15):

I have come up with a solution that is relatively accurate at evaluating when the angular initialisation is complete.

The directive is:

```
.directive('initialisation',['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function($scope) {
                    var to;
                    var listener = $scope.$watch(function() {
                        clearTimeout(to);
                        to = setTimeout(function () {
                            console.log('initialised');
                            listener();
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('initialised');
                        }, 50);
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

That can then just be added as an attribute to the `body` element and then listened for using `$scope.$on('initialised', fn)`

It works by assuming that the application is initialised when there are no more $digest cycles. $watch is called every digest cycle and so a timer is started (setTimeout not $timeout so a new digest cycle is not triggered). If a digest cycle does not occur within the timeout then the application is assumed to have initialised.

It is obviously not as accurate as satchmoruns solution (as it is possible a digest cycle takes longer than the timeout) but my solution doesn't need you to keep track of the modules which makes it that much easier to manage (particularly for larger projects). Anyway, seems to be accurate enough for my requirements. Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent solution. For projects when all code in one or two compressed files works very well.

Comment: This is fantastic solution.In case you have lots of code in jquery and you are trying to convert the code to angular step by step this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), you can listen for the `$viewContentLoaded`event.

*"$viewContentLoaded - fired once the view is loaded, **after the DOM is rendered**. The '$scope' of the view emits the event." - [Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events)*

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
function(event){ ... });
```

Comment: $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function() made the trick for me

Comment: downvoted for the 'which you should be'. What if I said "if you're using React instead of Angular (which you should be)..." ? Not a very attitude to have in this ecosystem IMHO.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck you are absolutely right. I edited my answer to remove my bias.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you. I actually added it to my run function, then changed $scope to $rootScope.

Comment: As Angular University pointed out in a different answer, $viewContentLoaded may not have been there originally, but it now works in the built-in ngRoute provider, in exactly the same way. With that in mind, I think this is the quick, simple, readable answer many (most?) future readers will be looking for.

Answer (score 3):

i observe DOM manipulation of angular with JQuery and i did set a finish for my app (some sort of predefined and satisfactory situation that i need for my app-abstract) for example i expect my ng-repeater to produce 7 result and there for i will set an observation function with the help of setInterval for this purpose .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var interval = setInterval(function(){

  if($("article").size() == 7){
     myFunction();
     clearInterval(interval);
  }

  },50);

});
```

Comment: I would not do this. Using intervals to check for stuff happening is not good practice, unscalable, and there are other ways to make things happen. Timers are for doing concrete tasks that need to happen after a certain time period, not for "guessing" when content or results are ready.

Comment: Not to mention that using a jquery timer against the angular platform is counter-productive- angular has a timeout class and you should use that otherwise you're straddling two frameworks and it becomes confusing very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Angular team and this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734):

> we now have $viewContentLoaded and $includeContentLoaded events that are emitted in ng-view and ng-include respectively. I think this is as close as one can get to knowing when we are done with the compilation.

Based on this, it seems this is **currently not possible** to do in a reliable way, otherwise Angular would have provided the event out of the box.

Bootstrapping the app implies running the digest cycle on the root scope, and there is also not a digest cycle finished event.

According to the Angular 2 [design docs](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7Ovm8bUYiUDR29iSkEyMk5pVUk&usp=drive_web&urp=https://angular.io/&pli=1&tid=0BxgtL8yFJbacUnUxc3l5aTZrbVk):

> Because of multiple digests, it is impossible to determine and notify the component that the model is stable. This is because notification can further change data, which can restart the binding process.

According to this, the fact that this is not possible is one the reasons why the decision was taken to go for a rewrite in Angular 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module, i.e. you don't have [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#$viewContentLoaded) event.

You can use another directive method:

```
    angular.module('someModule')
        .directive('someDirective', someDirective);

    someDirective.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$timeout']; //Inject services

    function someDirective($rootScope, $timeout){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            priority: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, //Lowest priority
            link    : function(scope, element, attr){
                $timeout(
                    function(){
                        $rootScope.$emit("Some:event");
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
```

Accordingly to [trusktr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23717845/3715524) it has lowest priority. Plus [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) will cause Angular to run through an entire event loop before callback execution.

[$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) used, because it allow to place directive in any scope of the application and notify only necessary listeners.

> $rootScope.$emit will fire an event for all $rootScope.$on listeners only. The interesting part is that $rootScope.$broadcast will notify all $rootScope.$on as well as $scope.$on listeners
>   [Source](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 2):

I had a fragment that was getting loaded-in after/by the main partial that came in via routing.

I needed to run a function after that subpartial loaded and I didn't want to write a new directive and figured out you could use a cheeky `ngIf`

Controller of parent partial:

```
$scope.subIsLoaded = function() { /*do stuff*/; return true; };
```

HTML of subpartial

```
<element ng-if="subIsLoaded()"><!-- more html --></element>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate JS with server-side data (JSP, PHP) you could add your logic to a service, that will be loaded automatically when your controller is loaded.

Additionally, if you want to react when all directives are done compiling/linking, you could add the appropriate proposed solutions above in the initialization logic.

```
module.factory('YourControllerInitService', function() {

    // add your initialization logic here

    // return empty service, because it will not be used
    return {};
});


module.controller('YourController', function (YourControllerInitService) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all great solutions, However, if you are currently using Routing then I found this solution to be the easiest and least amount of code needed.  Using the 'resolve' property to wait for a promise to complete before triggering the route. e.g.

```
$routeProvider
.when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "newsView.html",
    controller: "newsController",
    resolve: {
        message: function(messageService){
            return messageService.getMessage();
    }
}
```

})

[Click here for the full docs - Credit to K. Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

may be i can help you by this example

In the custom fancybox I show contents with interpolated values.

in the service, in the "open" fancybox method, i do

```
open: function(html, $compile) {
        var el = angular.element(html);
     var compiledEl = $compile(el);
        $.fancybox.open(el); 
      }
```

the $compile returns compiled data.
you can check the compiled data