# angular.js - evalAsync not called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

on the following jsFiddle i demonstrate a problem that makes me ponder. It stems from the need to send a system wide event to all scopes, telling them that the system has finished bootstrapping. 
In order to do that, i got the rootScope after bootstrapping, and called its evalAsync. Alas! its not executing.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/cusrC/8/

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
angular.bootstrap(body, ['app']);
var ngInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);

var rootScope = ngInjector.get('$rootScope');
var x = rootScope.$eval(function(scope) {   
        console.log('in eval');
        scope.$broadcast('onLoad'); 
        scope.$evalAsync(function(scope) {  
            console.log('in evalAsync');
            scope.$broadcast('onLoad'); 
        });
    });
console.log('x',x);
console.log('after');
});
```

many thanks for any idea or thought
Lior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark is right about calling the `$digest` function, but there's one more thing: you're not getting the right root scope.

`angular.bootstrap` returns the injector for the modules, which already pulls in the `'ng'` module.

[Here's your fiddle, modified](http://jsfiddle.net/cusrC/9/).

Comment: thanks @satchmorun. this solves it. however the issue is a bit deeper. I use templateUrls, and i see now that the link functions are delayed until all the partials are fetched from the server. Since $on listener registration happens during link function executions, any event broadcasting prior to that execution will not get to the $on's. not sure yet how to solve but FYI

Answer (score 3):

Since your code is running "outside" of Angular, you'll need to call rootScope.$digest() at the end of your sample code to cause a digest cycle to run.  Then the expression inside the $evalAsync() will be evaluated/executed.