# which event fires when AngularJS is done rendering?

Tags: angularjs, events, rendering

I have an application where I need to to some computation based on the final height of the content. Is there a generic event that fires when Angular is done rendering the current scope? Alternatively, is there a way to get notified if the DOM will no longer be modified (but is not nessecarily rendered yet)?

To clarify: I am not looking for an equivalent of DOM ready. ideally I'd like a notification every time any model changes have propagated to the dom. I am aware that i can watch angular expressions and have built a workaround that basically gets called x milliseconds after the last call of a watcher on a given expression. I thought however that there is a more 'angular way' to do that.

Comment: There is no end in DOM rendering . When you use angular view is changed when model changed. So your actual event is model change event. You can watch your model.

Comment: if you happen to be using ngView, there is an event called $viewContentLoaded. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView

Answer (score 1):

Angular has not provided a way to trigger an event when a page finished loading.

I found a great answer by [Lior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146636/lior)
who says "Angular hasn't provided a way to signal when a page finished loading, maybe because **'finished' depends on your application**..."

full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666515/1745230).