# AngularJs event to call after content is loaded

Tags: angularjs, events, loaded

I have a function which I want to call after page content is loaded. I read about $viewContentLoaded and it doesn't work for me. I am looking for something like

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 
     //Content goes here 
}, false);
```

Above call doesn't work for me in AngularJs controller.

Comment: This works well http://stackoverflow.com/q/14968690/6521116

Answer (score 167):

According to documentation of [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#event-$viewContentLoaded), it supposed to work

> Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.

`$viewContentLoaded` event is emitted that means to receive this event you need a parent controller like

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

From `MainCtrl` you can listen the event

```
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
  });
```

Check the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/isbTireh3w9OomDOvx87?p=preview)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that controllers have not fully initialized at this point.

Comment: @AshBlue what do mean by "Controllers have not fully initialized" ? Here at first initialize `MainCntl` then `BookCntl` after that `emit $viewContentLoaded` event.

Comment: @Reza He is correct, this event is fired when the dom is added but before angular has finished processing the dom. You can test this by adding a id or class as angular variable and try to find it in $viewContentLoaded with jQuery. You will not find it.

Comment: @Reza yes,Thomas is right the form element cannot access inside the $viewContentLoaded say,$scope.formName.elementName.$setValidity("validateRule", false); will throw "TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementName' of undefined"

Comment: The same can be called on $rootScope level. Instead of $scope.$on, it should be $rootScope.$on and inside of app.run() block

Comment: i use this and worked for disappearing loading icon div icon. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15463124/308578

Comment: This option will not work when you have `ng-repeat` and several nested directives that will generate HTML/Content based on complex loops and conditions. Rendering continues for some time, even after `$viewContentLoaded` event is triggered. How you can ensure that all elements have been fully rendered then execute certain code? Any feedback?

Comment: @tarekahf It is hard to give feedback without code or example. For framework it is really hard to know when your rendering will be finished, since some element may render as async. So you've to figure it out at which point you need to call the function. It would be nice if can you ask new question with your complex scenario or give some example or plunker!

Comment: @Reza I think I found a solution, please check it out and let me know what you think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46692965/4180447

Answer (score 116):

**Angular < 1.6.X**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('page loading completed');
});
```

**Angular >= 1.6.X**

```
angular.element(function () {
    console.log('page loading completed');
});
```

Comment: Does this go within the app.js ?

Comment: you can listen to it in your controllers.js

Comment: Works ok in main app.js file too.

Comment: That answer works for me! Just see that on documentation element page ' ready() (deprecated, use angular.element(callback) instead of angular.element(document).ready(callback)) '

Comment: This worked for me. The accepted answer approach does not work inside the controller.

Answer (score 76):

#### fixed - 2015.06.09

Use a directive and the angular element `ready` method like so:

#### js

```
.directive( 'elemReady', function( $parse ) {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function( $scope, elem, attrs ) {    
          elem.ready(function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                var func = $parse(attrs.elemReady);
                func($scope);
            })
          })
       }
    }
})
```

#### html

```
<div elem-ready="someMethod()"></div>
```

or for those using *controller-as* syntax...

```
<div elem-ready="vm.someMethod()"></div>
```

The benefit of this is that you can be as broad or granular w/ your UI as you like and you are removing DOM logic from your controllers.  I would argue this is the recommended *Angular* way.

You may need to prioritize this directive in case you have other directives operating on the same node.

Comment: this looks like a really good solution, but I couldn't make it work. it choked at `elem.ready( $scope.$apply( readyFunc( $scope )));`  Any ideas why that might be? Perhaps an update to angular happened? Anyway - it's an elegant approach, if it could work.

Comment: nm, I see what the issue was.  There was a typo on the `attrs.onReady`, should be what it is now.  The other issue was that I was calling it funky....
... what I get for converting coffeescript from memory to JS.

Comment: worked for me too - thanks!  I had to invoke it without the $scope in the html though, like this: `<div elem-ready="someMethod()"></div>`  For those coming after, this is a great way to run specific code after a template has been loaded, in my case, I needed to initialize popovers in bootstrap, but was having trouble doing it after that specific template had been loaded.

Comment: @domoarrigato I think that was my way of indicating the scope method.  I normally use *controller-as* syntax.  I will correct to limit confusion.

Comment: FYI, blue's answer does the same thing without the directive - any reason you can think of that this might be preferable?  In my use case, both worked.

Comment: I think in certain cases that may be fine, but my arguments against it are: I think the expectations of his code when just glancing is that that would return some text value to display in the DOM,ergo it requires a careful eye;  It doesn't allow any timing in terms of directive priority, you are stuck at the controller level unless you use `$timeout`; You're explicitly creating an addt. DOM node simply to execute non-dom logic; It's only reusable if that method resides far up in the $scope hierarchy such that child scopes inherit it;I just think it looks bad in an NG perspective;

Comment: Worked for me after adding a `$timeout(function() {})` around the `elem.ready()`. Otherwise it was throwing a `$digest already in progress` error. But anyway, thanks a ton! I have been struggling with this for the past hour.

Comment: I have this directive but I'm unable to access any functions in anything. Does it matter if the attibute is inside a ng-controller, I tried adding the function I'm calling but it can't see it...

Comment: Digging through the $scope appears to be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to pass the element to the method called when calling the method  on a controller?

Answer (score 70):

You can directly call it by adding `{{YourFunction()}}` after HTML element.

Here is a [`Plunker Link`](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQ8Y00YQeLT5PWiiC2Ke?p=preview).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I think you want to call a function when that html element is loaded. So call that function as mentioned above. If my guess is right about your doubt then this will work otherwise please elaborate your question. :)

Comment: This also works, even without the directive that is described in jusopi's answer.  I simply added {{YourFunction()}}, which is a function from the scopes controller, inside the tag in question (in my case, a div) - I think no further elaboration is needed.

Comment: When calling a function like this. Make sure its invoked once or otherwise the digest cycle will run infinite and shows an error

Comment: i like this solution, it is realy so simple

Comment: You are correct @Ashan. Need to add some condition within the function otherwise it will execute whenever the DOM will update.

Comment: Sorry- I thought this didn't work as expected.. but actually the simplest way to call a function after the `ng-repeat` has been updated - even from dynamic filters. Thanks +1

Comment: This is fantastic - only one problem. It appears that my function runs 5 times when I use this. I added a counter so it's working fine but I'm just wondering if anyone knows why that would occur... Seems a bit strange you know?

Comment: After days of ripping my hair out I stumble across this simple solution that is the only one that works for me! Thanks

Comment: Just amazing! I'm bout to die laughing :'D

Comment: This is absolutely awful... in how awesome it is, how simple it is, and how so many of us never even thought of it.

Comment: This deserves an Oscar

Comment: This causes infinite loops and should not be used. Use `<div ng-init="yourFuction()"></div>` as shown in [Saad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35649046/1843673)

Answer (score 25):

I had to implement this logic while handling with google charts. what i did was that at the end of my html inside controller definition i added.

```
  <body>
         -- some html here -- 
--and at the end or where ever you want --
          <div ng-init="FunCall()"></div>
    </body>
```

and in that function simply call your logic.

```
$scope.FunCall = function () {
        alert("Called");
}
```

Comment: I was using this but at the top of the page, the init required some div to be loaded already so by moving the ng-init to the bottom of the page fixed my issue, nice tip and it makes sense.

Comment: only answer that helped me with my problem (jquery mobile empty selection)

Comment: This is the real answer as it adapts to dynamically loaded controls and is super easy to implement.

Comment: this answer saved me some time, so elegant and effective for my use case

Answer (score 4):

```
var myM = angular.module('data-module');

myM.directive('myDirect',['$document', function( $document ){

    function link( scope , element , attrs ){

        element.ready( function(){

        } );

        scope.$on( '$viewContentLoaded' , function(){

            console.log(" ===> Called on View Load ") ;

        } );

    }

    return {
        link: link
    };

}] );
```

Above method worked for me

Answer (score 3):

you can call javascript version of onload event in angular js. this ng-load event can be applied to any dom element like div, span, body, iframe, img etc. following is the link to add ng-load in your existing project.

[download ng-load for angular js](https://github.com/darshu8/ng-load)

Following is example for iframe, once it is loaded  **testCallbackFunction**  will be called in controller

**EXAMPLE**

JS

```js
    // include the `ngLoad` module
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngLoad']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.testCallbackFunction = function() {
          //TODO : Things to do once Element is loaded
        };

    });
```

HTML

```html
  <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'> 
      <iframe src="test.html" ng-load callback="testCallbackFunction()">  
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add some example code to show how the OP can solve the problem

Comment: @jro Updated my ans. Hope it will be helpful  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a $digest already in progress error, this might help:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( $scope, elem, attrs ) {
            elem.ready(function(){

                if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        var func = $parse(attrs.elemReady);
                        func($scope);
                    })
                }
                else {

                    var func = $parse(attrs.elemReady);
                    func($scope);
                }

            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using `{{myFunction()}}` in the template but then found another way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30247770/2403881) using `$timeout` inside the controller. Thought I'd share it, works great for me.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', ['$timeout',
function($timeout) {
var self = this;

self.controllerFunction = function () { alert('controller function');}

$timeout(function () {
    var vanillaFunction = function () { alert('vanilla function'); }();
    self.controllerFunction();
});

}]);
```

Comment: I tried all the answers here and for some reason, $timeout is the only thing that worked for me.  Not sure why, but it could have something to do with ng-include and the timing of initiating services.

Comment: I added a plus one for {{myFunction()}}

Answer (score 1):

Running after the page load should partially be satisfied by setting an event listener to the window load event

```
window.addEventListener("load",function()...)
```

Inside the `module.run(function()...)` of angular you will have all access to the module structure and dependencies.

You can `broadcast` and `emit` events for communications bridges.

For example:

- module set onload event and build logic
- module broadcast event to controllers when logic required it
- controllers will listen and execute their own logic based on module onload processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want certain element to completely loaded, Use ng-init on that element .

e.g. `<div class="modal fade" id="modalFacultyInfo" role="dialog" ng-init="initModalFacultyInfo()"> ..</div>`

the initModalFacultyInfo() function should exist in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you have nested views - $viewContentLoaded gets triggered for every of the nested views. I've created this workaround to find the final $viewContentLoaded. Seems to work alright for setting $window.prerenderReady as required by Prerender (goes into .run() in the main app.js):

```
// Trigger $window.prerenderReady once page is stable
// Note that since we have nested views - $viewContentLoaded is fired multiple
// times and we need to go around this problem
var viewContentLoads = 0;
var checkReady = function(previousContentLoads) {
  var currentContentLoads = Number(viewContentLoads) + 0; // Create a local copy of the number of loads
  if (previousContentLoads === currentContentLoads) { // Check if we are in a steady state
    $window.prerenderReady = true; // Raise the flag saying we are ready
  } else {
    if ($window.prerenderReady || currentContentLoads > 20) return; // Runaway check
    $timeout(function() {checkReady(currentContentLoads);}, 100); // Wait 100ms and recheck
  }
};
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
  checkReady(-1); // Changed the state - ready to listen for end of render
});
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  viewContentLoads ++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTestApp = angular.module("myTestApp", []); 
myTestApp.controller("myTestController", function($scope, $window) {
$window.onload = function() {
 alert("is called on page load.");
};
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that work for me is the following

```
app.directive('onFinishRender', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                    if (!!attr.onFinishRender) {
                        $parse(attr.onFinishRender)(scope);
                    }
                });
            }

            if (!!attr.onStartRender) {
                if (scope.$first === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit('ngRepeatStarted');
                        if (!!attr.onStartRender) {
                            $parse(attr.onStartRender)(scope);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Controller code is the following

```
$scope.crearTooltip = function () {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
}
```

Html code is the following

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in $data" on-finish-render="crearTooltip()">
```

Answer (score -31):

I use `setInterval` to wait for the content loaded. I hope this can help you to solve that problem.

```
var $audio = $('#audio');
var src = $audio.attr('src');
var a;
a = window.setInterval(function(){
    src = $audio.attr('src');
    if(src != undefined){
        window.clearInterval(a);
        $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
            audioWidth: '100%'
        });
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Is people still recommend `setInterval` as a solution in **2016** ?

Comment: but there is no simple api in agular... how .. how to do it?