# Where to put code that should run after the views have been rendered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Edit: Actually, this isn't a duplicate. I'm asking how to run code once the *Dynamic* DOM is available, not the *Static* DOM:

[image]

Because my `textarea`s are inside an `ngRepeat`, so they aren't available in the Static DOM.

---

I'm using [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) in an Angular app. I'm trying to call `autosize` like this at the beginning of my controller:

```
autosize(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));
```

It doesn't work, presumably because at the time the function is called, `document.getElementsByTagName` is empty.

So I need to call the function *after* the DOM elements have been rendered. How can I do that?

Note: I also tried putting it in the `run` block, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried `<body onload='myFunction()'>` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21721060/4478897

Comment: @RaphaelAmoedo that wouldn't work for me; see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an instance of what is usually described as 'all DOM stuff goes to directives'. Integrating third-party code with Angular data binding will require some additional measures, but just for the initialization it's that easy:

```
app.directive('textarea', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      $timeout(function () {
        autosize(element[0]);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

`$timeout` with zero delay makes sure that the code runs after DOM has been rendered with initial state (this is the case for `ng-repeat` in particular).

Comment: So would declaring a `textarea` directive mess anything up with the angular's [built in](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea) one?

Comment: The doc refer to the directives [common to all form tags](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/validators.js). There's no `textarea` directive, but even if there was one, it is perfectly safe to have several directives with the same name, as long as their scopes, controllers and templates don't interfere (the same applies to every bunch of directives on the same element).