# Get height of div in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 3 div in which the data is filling from controller. and the div is dependent on dropdown select (particular div will be shown for particular dropdown value). the problem is that I am unable to get the height of that div when page is loaded and also when I changed the dropdown value. Everytime I am getting 0 height.

here is the code for html:

```
 <div class="brand-categoryWrp">
          <select ng-model="allbrandscategory" ng-change="catChange(allbrandscategory)">
              <option value="all">AllBrands</option>
              <option value="watches">Watches</option>
              <option value="pens">Pens</option>
          </select>
      </div>

   <div ng-show="firstdiv" allbrands-directive>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="res in brands">
          {{res.name}}
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
    <div ng-show="seconddiv" watches-directive>
      <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="res in brands1">
          {{res.name}}
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
    <div ng-show="thirddiv" pens-directive>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="res in brands2">
          {{res.name}}
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
```

and here is for controller:

```
// Code goes here

var myapp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myapp.controller('mycntrl',function($scope){


 $scope.allbrandscategory = 'all';
 $scope.firstdiv = true;

 $scope.brands = [
   {name: 'Adidas'},
   {name: 'Armani'}
 ];

  $scope.brands1 = [
    {name: 'Adidas1'},
    {name: 'Armani1'},
    {name: 'Fossil'}
];

  $scope.brands2 = [
    {name: 'Adidas2'},
    {name: 'Armani2'},
    {name: 'Mont blanc'},
    {name: 'calvin'}

];

  $scope.catChange = function(val){

   $scope.firstdiv = false;
   $scope.seconddiv = false;
   $scope.thirddiv = false;
   if(val == 'all')
   {
     $scope.firstdiv = true;
   }
   else if(val == 'watches')
   {
     $scope.seconddiv = true;
   }
   else if(val == 'pens')
   {
       $scope.thirddiv = true;
   }
 };

});

myapp.directive('pensDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
        //console.log(element);
        console.log("pens: "+element[0].offsetHeight);
       }
   };
 });
  myapp.directive('watchesDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
       // console.log(element);
        console.log('watches: '+element[0].offsetHeight);
       }
    };
  });
  myapp.directive('allbrandsDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
        //console.log(element);
        console.log("brand: "+element[0].offsetHeight);
       }
   };
  });
```

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JIVZ8I9MeiqoqQdB0mHJ?p=preview)

Comment: Why do you need height of a div

Comment: Height of div is unknown until it is actually drawn by browser. You can put $timeout() {console.log("brand: "+element[0].offsetHeight);} then you will see some value. However avoid this if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The `link` function is executed before the model data is bound to the view (the div does not contain any child elements when you're requesting the `offsetHeight`. Try wrapping it into a `$timeout(function() { /* ... */ })`, which will execute at the end of the current digest cycle.

Comment: I have already tried with $timeout function , for eg. I set the interval say 3 sec for all directive but what if I changed the dropdown after 3 sec. I will be getting the height of default selected items but wont be getting other divs height.

Comment: Also; change the `ng-show` to `ng-if` to trigger the `link` function to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AngularJs event to call after content is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded)

This has a nice answer to your problem and seems to work. Second answer down.

I tested on yours by adding the below to your allbranddirective:

```
        element.ready(function(){
          console.log("brand: "+element[0].offsetHeight);
        });
```

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<html>
```

```
 <div class="brand-categoryWrp">
          <select ng-model="divtoshow" ng-change="catChange(divtoshow)">
              <option value="allbrands-directive">AllBrands</option>
              <option value="watches-directive">Watches</option>
              <option value="pens-directive">Pens</option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div allbrands-directive><ul><li ng-repeat='res in brands'>{{res.name}}</li></ul></div>
```

JS:

```html
var myapp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myapp.controller('mycntrl',function($scope){

  $scope.brands = [{name: 'Adidas'}, {name: 'Armani'}];
  $scope.divtoshow = 'allbrands-directive'

  $scope.catChange = function(val){
    $scope.divtoshow = val;

    if (val == 'allbrands-directive'){
      $scope.brands = [{name: 'Adidas'}, {name: 'Armani'}];
    }else if (val == 'watches-directive') {
      $scope.brands = [{name: 'Adidas1'},{name: 'Armani1'},{name: 'Fossil'}];
    }else if (val == 'pens-directive') {
     $scope.brands = [{name: 'Adidas2'},{name: 'Armani2'},{name: 'Mont blanc'},{name: 'calvin'}];
    }
  }

});

  myapp.directive('allbrandsDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {         

            scope.$watch('brands', function(){
                console.log("brand: "+element[0].offsetHeight);
            });        
        }
    };
  });
```

So I have changed your code a bit, I have set up only one directive and in here I watch on a change of the brands variable, when this changes we then get the height of the element.

See plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/vZhn2aMRI6wKn3yVharS?p=preview

If you need each section in separate directives see nulls answers

Comment: It will work only for default selected item, what if I change the dropdown value? I wont be getting the other div height when i select other value from dropdown. (Actually I want the height of div related to dropdown. If I select pen then I want the height of thirddiv).

Comment: yes you are right, this is only getting the height of the initial element. I think you may need to create element directives, then call them onto the page with your on change. I don't have time to test this myself at the moment but will later.