# angularjs $scope.InputModelName is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one input field and trying to get the value from this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Application">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('Application', []);
app.controller('ApplicationRootController', function ($scope) {
    console.log("[Controller level value - which never come out] $scope.antiForgeryToken_test = " + $scope.antiForgeryToken_test);
    $scope.SubmitFunction = function(){
        console.log("[Value - which come out only after form submitted] $scope.antiForgeryToken_test = " + $scope.antiForgeryToken_test);
    };
});
</script>
</head>

<body>  
    <form id="ApplicationRoot" 
        ng-controller="ApplicationRootController" 
        ng-submit="SubmitFunction()" >

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

        <div id="AntiForgeryKeyHolder">
            <input 
                id="antiForgeryToken_test" 
                ng-model="antiForgeryToken_test"            
                ng-init="antiForgeryToken_test='PassKey123456789'"
                type="hidden" />
        </div>

    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

But what I got is `undefined`, So I tried using form submitting, then value come out.
 So my question is

How to get value from this simple input field without submitting form?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhvLtzqrHV6KqtrW0eiy)

## Updated

Why `console.log` give me `undefined` since the same code give me value when it was called by submitting form ?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. But your usage of `ng-init` is wrong, see doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit. If you want to initialize the value of model, you should do so in the controller itself.

Comment: Code looks fine what is your issue? Even plunker is working fine.

Comment: @DavidVotrubec, the `ng-init` is perfectly fine.

Comment: code in view - called after code inside controller, so you can do trick with `setTimeout` and in callback - check value that you need: for example http://plnkr.co/edit/FmzAuxN5UVmFp3iz9CI1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Code placed in view, executed after code placed in js controller. So when controller execute and call line

```
console.log("[Controller level value - which never come out] $scope.antiForgeryToken_test = " + $scope.antiForgeryToken_test);
```

`ng-init` in view yet not work.

For solve this you can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) like

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("[Controller level value - which never come out] $scope.antiForgeryToken_test = " + $scope.antiForgeryToken_test);
});
```

here callback execute after delay, so it can be after `ng-init`

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FmzAuxN5UVmFp3iz9CI1?p=preview)

Comment: Is there any event like `form loaded completely` rather than `setTimeout`?

Comment: @FrankMyatThu, you can see about [AngularJs event to call after content is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded). ofcourse if you use `ng-view`

Answer (score 0):

Wait till controller scope receives the ng-init data from UI.

```
var app = angular.module('Application', []);

app.controller('ApplicationRootController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){console.log($scope.antiForgeryToken_test);}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Is there any event like `form loaded completely` rather than `setTimeout`

Comment: checkout $viewContentLoaded documentation

Answer (score 0):

After I got great knowledge from @Grundy `code in view - called after code inside controller`

So, I was trying to fire code from controller only when the content is fully loaded. My final solution is below

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("[Value - After form loaded completly] $scope.antiForgeryToken_test = " + $scope.antiForgeryToken_test);
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eq4beo4tzQtdT4OZAOfy)

Comment: not recommended use jqLite in controller, seems like you try solve some another problem? why not just assign this token inside controller? Try see about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Grundy, My token key is come from `Asp.net Razor server side code`. I am not sure `controller js` can execute razor function `@GetAntiForgeryToken()`. More detial at http://techbrij.com/angularjs-antiforgerytoken-asp-net-mvc

Comment: yep, but you can save result for `@GetAntiForgeryToken()` in global variable and use it

Comment: or even move part with jqLite to directive

Comment: I am wondering if global variable approach will not be different since code inside the controller js run first. But I really interest to know detail how can I go with directive rather than jqLite, I will be very happy if you can guide me.

Comment: i mean not directive instead jqLite, but _move code with jqLite_ into directive. As for global var - so here do somewhere in start page: `var f = '@GetToken()';` and this `f` variable awail in any js code because it _global_

Comment: Great, you global variable solution also solve my problem. But most of every examples show anti-forgery key to keep at hidden form field. But using global var solution, I no longer need to use hidden field. Is this correct approach for anti-forgery cause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94083/discussion-between-grundy-and-frank-myat-thu).