# Get height of a element in ui-view

Tags: angularjs

I have a state that can have a variable height (depending on the content). I want to set that height as a css attribute for my background-color.

But I'm having trouble getting the correct height because the code fires before the content is loaded in the state.

I have this state,

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home.suggestions', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "suggestions": {
        templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_suggestions.html',
        controller: function(){
          showHeight = $('.suggestions-container-wrapper').outerHeight();
          console.log(showHeight)
        }
      },

    },
  })
```

But it always returns 175 (the height of the element before it loads the `ng-repeat` content.

How do I run the code after the all the calls are done?

Comment: I would probably create a directive for this and put it on the top level of your template

Answer (score 0):

Just found a simple solution. But a `ng-init` after the ng-repeat element, then it fires the function when it gets triggerd.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24817862/848706

```
%div{"ng-init" => "setHeight()"}
```

Controller,

```
$scope.setHeight = function (){
  $timeout(function(){
      showHeight = $('.suggestions-container-wrapper').outerHeight();
      console.log(showHeight)
    }, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs on [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView).  You might be able to do:

```
controller: function(){
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
        showHeight = $('.suggestions-container-wrapper').outerHeight();
        console.log(showHeight)
    });
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded) is also another post that discusses it.