# angularJS function similar to $.on('show'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to know a similar angular function to the one below. I have seen where different people said i should use ng-show .

```
$$('#tab1').on('show', function () {
myApp.alert('Tab 1 is visible');
 });
```

Comment: I don't think this question is being answered. It seems the request is to define a custom function for when an element is shown, not show or hide the element based on an expression which is what ng-show does. I believe a better match to this question is the Directive answer to [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded)

Answer (score 2):

Hey you should really check out [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow/#example) part of the AngularJS documentation about ng-show. It's a very easy and clear example.

Answer (score 1):

Angular equivalent directive is:

```
ng-show
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register to an `visibilityChanged` element instead of only changing the visibility of an element with `ng-show` you could create a directive with a link function.

```
angular.module('example', []).directive('example', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function() {

            //check if visible
            myApp.alert('Tab 1 is visible');
        });
    }
    return {
       link: link
   };
}]);
```