# $timeout is not working in my code. Im trying to delay the html elements to display after specific time using this directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout

Here is the code I'm using. I'm trying to display the html contents which comes under this tag after 4 seconds

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function() {
  var directive = {};
  directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.attr("style","display:none") 

    function show() {
      element.attr("style","display:inline")
    }

    $timeout(function() {
       show();
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$timeout is a service which should be injected. Change the below line

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function() {
    //your code
});
```

to

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function($timeout) {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! it works fine now, but there is an another issue came up in the same. $timeout is working when page is loading for the first time. If i go to another page and come back delayed function is not delaying, its instantly displaying its elements

Comment: please create a fiddle and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

Include the $timeout dependency in your directive, like this:

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function($timeout) {
    //your code...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! it works fine now, but there is an another issue came up in the same. $timeout is working when page is loading for the first time. If i go to another page and come back delayed function is not delaying, its instantly displaying its elements

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inject the $timeout service in your directive, so it's undefined:

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function($timeout) {
```

You also forgot to return the directive from the function:

```
return directive;
```

Otherwise, it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/z0P6ENRyXvyYjNr7KqzV?p=preview

Note that is couls be reduced to

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.attr("style","display:none") 

      $timeout(function() {
         element.attr("style","display:inline");
      }, 4000);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! it works fine now, but there is an another issue came up in the same. $timeout is working when page is loading for the first time. If i go to another page and come back delayed function is not delaying, its instantly displaying its elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject dependencies to the directive like in other modules:

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
   return = {
        link: function($scope, element){
            element.attr("style","display:none")
            //use $timeout
           $timeout(function() {
              element.attr("style","display:inline");
           }, 4000);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! it works fine now, but there is an another issue came up in the same. $timeout is working when page is loading for the first time. If i go to another page and come back delayed function is not delaying, its instantly displaying its elements

Comment: You can refer this link to bind your function after the template is loaded - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Because while loading the page some unwanted html elements are flickering in the screen in Internet Explorer browser. So i wanted to delay that flickering elements, thats where im using this directive. As im new and u have suggested this link can u suggest me how to go abt this issue

Comment: `elem.ready(function(){
            $timeout(function() {
              element.attr("style","display:inline");
           }, 4000);
          });`    Replace your timeout code with above code and try.

Comment: I tried using this sir! but my main page is only not loading if i include this code. Is elem.ready is used here to load the contents after page is completely loaded?

Comment: Please replace **elem** with **element** and try

Comment: nope! still not loading. Any idea what can be the problem here

Comment: Can you share JSfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $timeout into your directive

```
Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', ['$timeout',ieUtilsError]);

 function ieUtilsError($timeout){
 return {

  $timeout(function() {
     element.attr("style","display:inline");
  }, 4000);

   };
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! it works fine now, but there is an another issue came up in the same. $timeout is working when page is loading for the first time. If i go to another page and come back delayed function is not delaying, its instantly displaying its elements

Comment: Try to use $interval and please upvote if answer is acceptable thanks.