# How to delay directive compile until after window load event

Tags: angularjs

I want to delay certain directives to only compile after the window load event. They are below the fold and are slowing down the overall Angular bootstrapping process.

So to this end, I want to create an attribute directive that I can add to directives that will delay their compile function - is this possible?

Comment: This link might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded

Comment: Did you try wrapping `ng-if` around the directives. Initially, `ng-if` will be `false`. Once you load the document set `ng-if` to `true`. All the directives will start to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $timeout you can put delay functionality.

```
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $timeout(function(){

    });        
}
```

and don't forget to inject `$timeout`

```
.directive('directiveName', function($timeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your logic after `onload` event. In order to do this, you should use `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()`.

Hope it helps!