# angular $parse is blowing up as a directive parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to follow this answer to an older question, but I'm getting a crash on $parse as the function parameter. Why might it not recognize $parse?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571230/1481314

```
.directive('elementReady', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
                    elem.ready(function () {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            var func = $parse(attrs.elementReady);
                            func($scope);
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting? Have you tried specifying it as a dependency in the array format using ```['$parse', function ($parse){...}]```?

Comment: Have you minified the scripts?

Comment: Like @devqon said, if you minified the script and did not put the dependency or injected it elsewhere it will fail

Comment: @HenryZou That worked! Make your comment into an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the injection in string format. This is only needed when uglifying your source code.

## Approach 1: use array format when declaring angular injections

```
.directive('elementReady', ['$parse' function elementReady($parse) {
  ... 
}]);
```

## Approach 2: use named function and manually specify injection

```
.directive('elementReady', elementReady)

function elementReady($parse) {
  ... 
}
elementReady.$inject = ['$parse'];
```

## Approach 3: use ng-annotation to automate this

GRUNT: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-annotate

GULP: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate/