# AngularJs execute code after a view has been rendered

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of nested views and load under the previous view. I am trying to create a scrollTo directive that will scroll to the start of the view when the view has loaded, but I can't get it to work.
I need to execute my code after the view has loaded and all the html/images have been downloaded.

Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Comment: does wrapping it with `$timeout` do anything?

Comment: Are you sure about images? This is a bit strange to force user wait for all images.

Comment: Yes I am sure, it can't scroll if there are no images because the content height would be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the content to be loaded using `angular.element(callback)`:

Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30258904/1904479

Comment: I will give this a test, if it works I will mark it as the answer