# ngShow not updating when value changes in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

In my AngularJS app, I am displaying a loading icon to the user until all the content has loaded. I have two conditions in the controller which change once content has loaded, like so:

```
function form1200questionnaireCtrl(){
    vm.loading = true;
    vm.patentsLoaded = true;

    angular.element(function () {
        vm.loading = false;
        vm.patentsLoaded = true;
        console.log('should hit', vm.loading, vm.patentsLoaded)
    });
}
```

---

```
<div data-ng-show="$ctrl.loading" >
    <img src="assets/imgs/icons/spinner-loader.gif">
</div>
<div data-ng-show="$ctrl.patentsLoaded" class="animate-show">  
    //all content 
</div>
```

My issue is that the values of both `vm.loading` and `vm.patentsLoaded` change value as I have logged it into the console, but the loading gif displays for around 10-15 seconds before hiding and the content displaying.

***Question***

Why is the view not picking up the change in the scope immediately with `ng-show`?

Comment: why need to put inside `angular.element`?

Comment: i think the sample code you have here has `vm.loading = true` twice . I am sure you meant `vm.patentsLoaded = true` over there ...

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `angular.element`? Why not try to use `ng-cloak`?

Comment: @brk I was following answers in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded and yes I made the mistake in the question. Corrected now

Comment: But the fact is that values have changed, so why is the view not updating immediately?

Comment: try $scope.$apply() in your function soon after you toggle the variables.

Comment: what is your AnulgarJS version?

Comment: How is `form1200questionnaireCtrl()` being called? Is being called from outside the Angular digest cycle?