# How do a grab a DOM element as soon as it has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-init

I'm working on an angular application that uses ng-grid through out on one of the grids I have a cell template with an ng-init function attached to one of it's dom elements.

```
var cellTemplate = '<div class="fooProperty" ng-init="setIcon($event, \'foo\',row.entity.foo)" ng-class="{\'foo_enabled\' : row.entity.foo, \'foo_disabled\' : !row.entity.hasFoo}"  ng-click="changeRole($event, \'foo\')" title="Foo Bar"></div>'
```

The code I have written for setIcon in my directive is

```
scope.setIcon = function($event,type,iconInfo){
  var target = $event.target; 
  var row = (target).parent().parent();
  console.log(type+": "+iconInfo);
  console.log(row);
};
```

The problem I'm having is that when the ng-init function fires I get an error message saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target'` of undefined at `var target = $event.target;`.

**EDIT:**

So the issue is that I can't use `$event` on `ng-init` since no DOM event happens. My question now is how can I edit the above code to grab the DOM element as soon as it's loaded (essentially I need to know the proper angular equivalent of onload)?

Comment: [`$event` is not available with nginit](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-). There is no event to pass, since no DOM event happens on ng-init. It is also out of spec to use ng-init other than for aliasing ng-repeats special properties.

Comment: Then I should probably ask a separate question instead. What's the proper Angular equivalent of JavaScript or JQuery's onload event?

Comment: You can update the same question and post your actual issue with relevant code and possibly a demo. This is an x/y problem which makes you do this way.

Comment: I made the edits that you suggested.

Comment: Here is your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23717845/2710175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use directive instead of ng-init:

```
app.directive('domLoaded', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link : function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $timeout(function () {
        var row = $($element).parent().parent();
        console.log(row);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

usage:

```
cellTemplate = '<div class="fooProperty" dom-loaded ng-class="{\'foo_enabled\' : row.entity.foo, \'foo_disabled\' : !row.entity.hasFoo}"  ng-click="changeRole($event, \'foo\')" title="Foo Bar"></div>'
```