# How to call a function after AngularJS render all views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to call a simple function, after all AngularJS views loaded successfully.

```
function hello() {
  alert('All AngularJS works are done');
}

<!-- Below code is example about how I need a function for AngularJS loaded event -->
app.onAngularLoaded(function () { hello(); });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968690/sending-event-when-angular-js-finished-loading

Answer (score 4):

Try setting a timeout with a value of 0. That will happen after the current set of digest cycles.

```
$timeout(function(){...}, 0);
```

Comment: where I have to put this code? just inside <script> tag or $(document).ready. Am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $timeout is not defined"

Comment: You run it in an angular controller or directive or somewhere within your angular code. `$timeout` is an angular wrapper for `timeout` that gets injected if you write a controller like this: `myModule.controller('MyController', function($timeout){...});`

Answer (score 1):

The problem w. what you are trying to tackle is that if you are using something like `ng-include` or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) then you won't know when those are finished loading until **they** are requested and loaded.  It's an on-demand scenario.

You may however be looking to do something *post-bootstrapping* of the angular process?  If that is the case you need to do something like this on you main/root angular module:

```
angular.module('app', [ ... any ng-dependencies here ...])
.controller(...)
.controller(...)
.directive(...)
.service(...)

//then here is where you do your post-bootstrapping logic
.run( function(){
   //code here
})
```

more info here - [angular module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks)

Comment: you switch between the } and ) in the end of the run function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directive to get it.

```
var homeApp = angular.module('home', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);
homeApp
    .directive("pagecontent",
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            link: function() {
                alert('All AngularJS works are done');
            },

            templateUrl: "template path",
        }
```