# jQuery-Selectric with angular not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

We are using jQuery-Selectric for custom drop down and it works well. But when I apply it in ng-repeat loop for dynamically added drop-down, it is applied but the data is not coming.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your mark up I would suggest that the issue is that selectric is firing before the angular ajax call has completed. in other words the markup has not arrived yet.

[I would recommend reading this post on firing javascript after angular has finished loading:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968690/sending-event-when-angular-js-finished-loading)