# Notification when component containing multiple views is rendered in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an application using angular 1.6.9. We are using components.

Issue:

I would like open one modal dialog when the main view is loaded completely.
Main Veiw contains multiple views which are like different components.

I have tried lots of things like

- $postLink()
- $viewContentLoaded
- creating directive as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968690/sending-event-when-angular-js-finished-loading/23717845#23717845)

But still I am not get to the event which is emitted when full view is rendered.
Is there a way to figure that out?

Comment: Such event doesn't exist. Whats so important to display this modal after "everything" have been loaded?

Comment: This is the requirement, but is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I think you can find a solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968690/sending-event-when-angular-js-finished-loading/23717845#23717845  ... but why do you need to display this modal after "everthing" has been loaded?

Comment: @lin you are pointing to same link that I have mentioned above. And I cannot control requirements.

Comment: Yes I know. But could you please answer my question?

Comment: if url querystring contains some keyword then this main view will be opened along with modal dialog. This modal can be also be opened by button click in main view .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167019/discussion-between-lin-and-anand).

Answer (score -1):

$timeout will execute what's inside it on the next digest cycle. Drop it in your views controller.

Comment: I have tried this     this.$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', () => {
      $timeout((): any => {
        console.log('view content loaded  ');
      }, 0);
  
    });    This is again called multiple times.

Comment: Don't put it on the event as that gets called multiple times. Just directly on the controller.

Comment: do you have example?

Comment: Can you post a working example of what you're working on? I can help modify it.